# How to round each number of my 2d numpy array using a function?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I have an array made of float numbers called A, I define the following function

```
def foo(x):
    return round(x)
```

Then I run the following

```
B = np.apply_along_axis(foo, axis=1, arr=A)
```

Expecting to get B, where each number is rounded

instead I got this

> TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define **round** method